# OSX to Win10 via RDP, Increase Win10 Audio on OSX

Tags: windows-10, macos, audio, remote-desktop

I am RDPing into Windows 10 via OS X, and I am looking to increase the volume of the sounds coming from the RDP session, Windows 10 volume mixer is maxed out, but the sounds are not that loud.

So here is my deal, I am listening to DubStep that is playing on my OS X machine, and I want the notification sounds from Windows 10 to be louder than the DubStep preferably. If not louder, to at least match the volume level of the music playing.

Right now it is kind of hard to notice the notification sounds from Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get individual application volumes is to use something like [Rogue Amoeba's SoundSource](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) At 35 bucks it's not cheap, but it is very good [as are most things from Rogue Amoeba.]

Alternatively, turn down the volume on iTunes or whatever you're using & turn the Mac's overall volume up to compensate.